# Why is a 'Catch' block called twice in a Realm schema version check? in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am working with **Swift 5,** and **Realm 3.14.1**, using **Xcode 10.4**, developing for **iOS 11** and up.

I have the following block in the Realm migration, to report the current Schema version.

```
func setupRealm() {
    print("Get version")
    do {
        let fileUrlIs = try schemaVersionAtURL(Realm.Configuration().fileURL!)
        print("*** Stored Schema version \(fileUrlIs)")
    } catch  {
        print("No previous Realm DB")
    }
    //Run Realm Migration
    let config = Realm.Configuration( schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Event.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) in
                //if let object = newObject {
                //  object["entregaId"] = ""
                //}
            })
        }
    })
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

For some reason, when the app is installed and run for the first time, the printout of "No previous Realm DB" is printed twice.

Is there something wacky in my code?

Rgds...  e

Comment: That snippet isn't revealing enough. Can you please include the entire function and indicate where the function is located? Also, that's not a good way to get the prior schema version; you should be using `migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in`

Comment: I just updated the code to include the whole migration function....

Comment: Huh. It's a little unclear why you are are getting schema from a fileURL with that call - it doesn't appear to have any other function - it's not wrong but it doesn't do anything in this case. You can really just `print(oldSchemaVersion)` within the `migrationBlock: {` closure to do that. To your question; obviously the setupRealm function is being called twice at some point but there's nothing in that particular code that would do that. I think the duplicate call lies elsewhere so as is, the question is not answerable. i.e. setupRealm is being called twice from something outside that code.

Comment: Hi @Jay. The schemaVersionAtURL function does indeed return the schema version of the database.... (I found it somewhere and have been using it for over a year in multiple apps)   The double call happens only when the app is recently installed and thus Realm has not configured the DB....    I checked your recommendation, but oldSchemaVersion seems to be available only when there is a migration....   I want to check the DB version regardless of having migration or not...   The question may be (as you suggest) not answerable, and the double call just an annoyance..... : )

Comment: I understand the question and it's fine to ask, and thanks for the clarification. If *No previous Realm DB* is being printed twice then setupRealm is being called twice, which would not be related to the code in the question - that's a symptom of the issue. Perhaps the issue is where `setupRealm` is being called from. Probably need to include that code to try to nail down the issue.